# C program for GCC and MS Visual Express C++ works only for GCC

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

I'm trying to make my school assignment to work in both GCC and MS VS enviroments, but for some reason, it fails to compile in MS VS...

The errors are:

> warning C4627: '#include ': skipped when looking for precompiled header use - Add directive to 'Stdafx.h' or rebuild precompiled header

or

> unexpected #endif (the one after #include "Stdafx.h")

or

When I put the "Stdafx.h" header to first line, it behaves like there's no stdio and everything (HANDLE, int, etc. ) is illegal declaration.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #include "Stdafx.h" 
    #include <windows.h>
#endif // _MSC_VER

#ifdef __GNUC__
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif  // __GNUC__

#ifdef _MSC_VER

int main ()
{       
    printf("___MS VS Studio/Express compiler___\n");

    /*some stuff here*/ 
    return 0;
 }
#endif  //_MSC_VER

#ifdef __GNUC__ 

int main()
{
    printf("___GCC compiler___\n");
    /*some other stuff here*/
     return 0;
 }
 #endif // __GNUC__
```

It works fine on GCC and I suspect it has something to do with the #includes in #ifdef conditions in MS VS, but I dunno how to do it correctly..

Can anyone please correct me on how to make this work properly?
Any useful advice welcome, thanks!

Comment: Please show your "Stdafx.h" file

Comment: // stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
// project.pch will be the pre-compiled header
// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information

#include "stdafx.h"

// TODO: reference any additional headers you need in STDAFX.H
// and not in this file

Answer (score 0):

Your file should start like below, the "stdafx.h" file must be included first. This is required by Visual Studio's "precompiled headers" feature.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
    #include "Stdafx.h" 
    #include <windows.h>
#endif // _MSC_VER

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


#ifdef __GNUC__
    #include <unistd.h>
#endif  // __GNUC__
```

If this doesn't workmtry to do launch the **Build - Rebuild Solution** command.

If this doesn't work you can remove the precompiled header like this:

- Launch the **Project - Properties** command
- In the **C/C++ - Precompoiled Headers** tab click on "Precompiled Headers" and select "Not Using Precompiled Headers".

Comment: It still does not compile, a lot of errors like
"error C2275: 'HANDLE' : illegal use of this type as an expression"
 comes up.. The code should be correct and it compiles in MS E when I do not use the #ifdef macros..